# Clean Up HTML in Python

Tags: python, html, django

I'm aggregating content from a few external sources and am finding that some of it contains errors in its HTML/DOM. A good example would be HTML missing closing tags or malformed tag attributes. Is there a way to clean up the errors in Python natively or any third party modules I could install?

Comment: Were any of these answers what you were looking for?  If you need more info we can certainly help?

Comment: @JudoWill: Yeah I was able to get BeautifulSoup and Tidy set up. Unfortunately they weren't catching a lot of the issues I was having. I ended up building my own function to go cycle through the DOM and fix the issues. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you post your own function as an answer.  This is an issue that I have a lot of the time and I'm always looking for new solutions. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would suggest [Beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).  It has a wonderful parser that can deal with malformed tags quite gracefully.  Once you've read in the entire tree you can just output the result.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
tree = BeautifulSoup(bad_html)
good_html = tree.prettify()
```

I've used this many times and it works wonders.  If you're simply pulling out the data from bad-html then BeautifulSoup really shines when it comes to pulling out data.

Comment: Take caution with performance, BeautifulSoup is very expansive.

Comment: @Tarantula. I agree, BeautifulSoup is pretty slow, but its the only thing I've ever seen that can parse some of those crazy malformed HTML based tables out there.

Answer (score 11):

An example of cleaning up HTML using the [**lxml.html.clean.Cleaner**](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.clean.Cleaner-class.html) module.

Requires the `lxml` module — `pip install lxml` (it's a native module written in C so it might be faster than pure python solutions).

```python
import sys

from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner


def sanitize(dirty_html):
    cleaner = Cleaner(page_structure=True,
                  meta=True,
                  embedded=True,
                  links=True,
                  style=True,
                  processing_instructions=True,
                  inline_style=True,
                  scripts=True,
                  javascript=True,
                  comments=True,
                  frames=True,
                  forms=True,
                  annoying_tags=True,
                  remove_unknown_tags=True,
                  safe_attrs_only=True,
                  safe_attrs=frozenset(['src','color', 'href', 'title', 'class', 'name', 'id']),
                  remove_tags=('span', 'font', 'div')
                  )

    return cleaner.clean_html(dirty_html)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    with open(sys.argv[1]) as fin:

        print(sanitize(fin.read()))
```

Check out the [**docs**](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.clean.Cleaner-class.html) for a full list of options you can pass to the Cleaner.

Comment: how it can clean from code tags (div) with specific 'id' or 'class'? (completely, include text).

Comment: @triwo: this is not supported ootb, but you can parse the markup and remove the nodes  by class or id with lxml; e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226490

Answer (score 4):

There are python bindings for the [HTML Tidy Library Project](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/), but automatically cleaning up broken HTML is a tough nut to crack. It's not so different from trying to automatically fix source code -- there are just too many possibilities. You'll still need to review the output and almost certainly make further fixes by hand.

Answer (score 3):

I am using [lxml](http://lxml.de/) to convert HTML to proper (well-formed) XML:

```
from lxml import etree
tree   = etree.HTML(input_text.replace('\r', ''))
output_text = '\n'.join([ etree.tostring(stree, pretty_print=True, method="xml") 
                          for stree in tree ])
```

... and doing lot of removing of 'dangerous elements' in the middle....

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the tidy_document function in tidylib module.

```
import tidylib
html = '<html>...</html>'
inputEncoding = 'utf8'
options = {
    str("output-xhtml"): True, #"output-xml" : True
    str("quiet"): True,
    str("show-errors"): 0,
    str("force-output"): True,
    str("numeric-entities"): True,
    str("show-warnings"): False,
    str("input-encoding"): inputEncoding,
    str("output-encoding"): "utf8",
    str("indent"): False,
    str("tidy-mark"): False,
    str("wrap"): 0
    };
document, errors = tidylib.tidy_document(html, options=options)
```