# Finding html element with class using lxml

Tags: class, python-3.x, lxml

I've searched everywhere and what I most found was doc.xpath('//element[@class="classname"]'), but this does not work no matter what I try.

code I'm using

```
import lxml.html

def check():
    data = urlopen('url').read();
    return str(data);

doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(check())
el = doc.xpath("//div[@class='test']")
print(el)
```

It simply prints an empty list.

Edit:
How odd. I used google as a test page and it works fine there, but it doesn't work on the page I was using (youtube)

Here's the exact code I'm using.

```
import lxml.html
from urllib.request import urlopen
import sys

def check():
    data = urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/user/TopGear').read(); #TopGear as a test
    return data.decode('utf-8', 'ignore');


doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(check())
el = doc.xpath("//div[@class='channel']")
print(el)
```

Comment: `'url'` is a 3-character string. It is not a HTML file.

Comment: Obviously I did that instead of posting the real url.

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 36):

The TopGear page that you use for testing doesn't have any `<div class="channel">` elements. But this works (for example):

```
el = doc.xpath("//div[@class='channel-title-container']")
```

Or this:

```
el = doc.xpath("//div[@class='a yb xr']")
```

To find `<div>` elements with a `class` attribute that *contains* the string `channel`, you could use

```
el = doc.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'channel')]")
```

Comment: `branded-page channel` is not the same as `channel`.

Comment: But, according to css, that element has two classes, branded-page and channel. So why wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, according to CSS there are two classes. But XPath does not know about the rules of CSS. To XPath, `branded-page channel` is just a string with no special meaning.

Comment: That's actually helpful, thanks. Just as a test, I tried to get an element on this page, and it's not working either. This is really starting to piss me off.  el = doc.xpath('//a[@class="vote-accepted-off"]')          It appears that it doesn't like to find elements that don't have child elements.

Comment: Just to complete your answer, we can aslo use **not()** for negation.Example:

**`el = doc.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'channel') and not(contains(@class, 'disabled'))]")`**

Answer (score 3):

You can use lxml.cssselect to simplify `class` and `id` request: http://lxml.de/dev/cssselect.html

Answer (score 1):

HTML uses classes (a lot), which makes them convenient to hook XPath queries. However XPath has no knowledge/support of CSS classes (or even space-separated lists) which makes classes a pain in the ass to check: the canonically correct way to look for elements having a specific class is:

```
//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), '$className')]
```

In your case this is

```
el = doc.xpath(
    "//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), 'channel')]"
)
# print(el)
# [<Element div at 0x7fa44e31ccc8>, <Element div at 0x7fa44e31c278>, <Element div at 0x7fa44e31cdb8>]
```

or use own XPath function hasclass(*classes)

```
def _hasaclass(context, *cls):
    return "your implementation ..." 

xpath_utils = etree.FunctionNamespace(None)
xpath_utils['hasaclass'] = _hasaclass

el = doc.xpath("//div[hasaclass('channel')]")
```

Comment: The second arg in `contains()` should also have spaces added (like `' $className '` and `' channel '`). Otherwise you'll still match classes like `somechannel`.